# how to store username/passwords securely (hash won't do) on a DB

Tags: security, postgresql, grails, passwords, grails-plugin

Imagine this situation: your users give you their credentials (username/password) to access a third party service. So you have to produce those credentials when connecting to the service, you cannot just store a salted hash.

The environment is Grails, with psql as DB. From the programmer point of view, ideally the user/password would still be part of the domain objects (so they are easy to use).

What would be the best practice to securely store them?

Comment: I'm guessing the 3rd party service doesn't offer nice, revokeable API key/secret based access?

Comment: btw, if your app able to decrypt/decode this credentials, then a hacker, who have full access to your app, will be able to do the same (just by using your existing code)

Comment: @CraigRinger correct, no way around that

Comment: It's an imperfect solution (as covered below), but one option is to encrypt fields in your domain using Jasypt: http://grails.org/plugin/jasypt-encryption

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm *not* a security or crypto expert; this is my understanding based on my reading and research, but is very far from authoritative advice. Get the advice of web-app security professionals and get a proper security audit.)*

The best you can really do is have your app unable to decrypt them when the user isn't actively logged in.

Encrypt the credentials with a key based partially on the user's raw, unhashed password. You *never* store the user's password to log into your service on your systems, of course, so you only have access to it for a brief moment during authentication (and only then because the web hasn't caught up with the mid-90's and adopted sane challenge-response authentication schemes). You can, at the moment of user log-in, decrypt the saved credentials for the 3rd party services and store them in the volatile server-side session for the user.

For the encryption key you might hash the username and user raw password with a large-ish  salt value you generate randomly for each (user,3rd-party-credential) pair and store alongside the encrypted credentials. The salt should be different to their salt used for their stored hashed password.

This is far from ideal and has all sorts of problems - but the credentials won't be accessible after the user's session expires or they log our and you purge their session.

It also means your app cannot act on their behalf when they aren't actively logged in, a limitation that may be a showstopper for you depending on your requirements.

A weaker option is to have a key for all user credentials that's manually entered by the sysadmin when the app is re-started. This key has to be stored in memory, but it's at least not sitting on the disk or in the database, so someone stealing a dump of your database will have a much harder time decrypting the stored credentials.

Neither option will help you if the attacker finds a way to trick your app into revealing those domain objects after decryption - or getting it to let them impersonate that user, getting it to perform actions on the 3rd party service on behalf of another user, etc. It'll at least protect against theft of database dumps and similar attacks, though.

One further recommendation: Rather than using `pgcrypto` to the crypto in the DB, do it on the application side. This means the DB never sees the key material required to decrypt the data; it can never be leaked into database logs, sniffed out of `pg_stat_activity`, etc.

Comment: thanks for the very elaborate contribution. Your first idea is great...but unfortunately a showstopper for us, we DO need to use the credentials when the user is not logged in. The second suggestion is the best I got so far...thanks!